# JavaFX : display pdf with icepdf

Tags: java, swing, pdf, javafx, javafx-8

I was looking for a way to display pdf files in my JavaFx application. and I'm trying to do that with icePDF but i only seem to find code for swing. Right now I inserted the code into a SwingNode and embedded it into a pane but the problem is that the JPanel that contains the icePDF pdf reader that does not fit the size of the JavaFx pane.

This is how i do it :

```
private void handleApercuBtn(){
SwingController controller = new SwingController();

SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller);

JPanel viewerComponentPanel = factory.buildViewerPanel();

ComponentKeyBinding.install(controller, viewerComponentPanel);

controller.getDocumentViewController().setAnnotationCallback(
  new org.icepdf.ri.common.MyAnnotationCallback(
         controller.getDocumentViewController()));

final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode,viewerComponentPanel);

apercuPane.getChildren().add(swingNode);

controller.openDocument(filePath);
}
```

How can I fit the JPanel that contains the icePDF reader into my pane (apercuPane)? How can I not use Swing code to do this?

Comment: i want to know too :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author Sudarshan
 */
public class PDFFXMLController implements Initializable {    
    private static String pdfPath;
    private SwingController swingController;
    private JComponent viewerPanel;
    @FXML
    private BorderPane borderPane;  
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
  @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
     String pdfPathLoad;
    try {
        pdfPathLoad = loadPDF("http://21-04-2017/17854381660C617.pdf");    
        createViewer(borderPane);
        openDocument(pdfPathLoad );
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PDFFXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }

    private void createViewer(BorderPane borderPane) {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
                swingController = new SwingController();
                swingController.setIsEmbeddedComponent(true);
                PropertiesManager properties = new PropertiesManager(System.getProperties(),
                        ResourceBundle.getBundle(PropertiesManager.DEFAULT_MESSAGE_BUNDLE));
                properties.set(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_TOOLBAR_FIT, "false");
                properties.set(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_TOOLBAR_ROTATE, "false");
                properties.set(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_TOOLBAR_TOOL, "false");
                properties.set(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL, "1.25");
                properties.setBoolean(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_STATUSBAR_VIEWMODE, Boolean.FALSE);
                properties.set(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_TOOLBAR_PAGENAV, "false");
                ResourceBundle messageBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(PropertiesManager.DEFAULT_MESSAGE_BUNDLE);
                new FontPropertiesManager(properties, System.getProperties(), messageBundle);
                swingController.getDocumentViewController().setAnnotationCallback(
                        new org.icepdf.ri.common.MyAnnotationCallback(swingController.getDocumentViewController()));
                SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(swingController, properties);
                viewerPanel = factory.buildViewerPanel();
                viewerPanel.revalidate();
                SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
                swingNode.setContent(viewerPanel);
                borderPane.setCenter(swingNode);
                swingController.setToolBarVisible(false);
                swingController.setUtilityPaneVisible(false);
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        }
    }
    private void openDocument(String document) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swingController.openDocument(document);
                viewerPanel.revalidate();
            }
        });
    }
    public String loadPDF(String adresse) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("In load PDf");
        if (!adresse.toLowerCase().endsWith("pdf")) {
            return null;
        }
        String fileName = adresse.substring(adresse.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                adresse.lastIndexOf("."));
        String suffix = adresse.substring(adresse.lastIndexOf("."),
                adresse.length());
        File temp = null;
    try {
            InputStream input = new URL(adresse).openStream();
            temp = File.createTempFile(fileName, suffix);
            temp.deleteOnExit();
            Files.copy(input, Paths.get(temp.toURI()),
                    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(PDFFXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        return temp.getAbsolutePath();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a late answer but maybe someone will find this helpful in the future. Here is how we do it at my company. Maybe there are better ways to do it but at least it works.

In short the PDF is loaded as an IcePDF document and converted to an image that can be displayed.

Example Code:

```
@FXML
private ScrollPane scrollPane;

private final ObjectProperty<ImageView> currentImage;

...

scrollPane.contentProperty().bind(currentImage);

...

org.icepdf.core.pobjects.Document currentDocument = new Document();
try {
    File file = new File("/path/to/pdf");
    currentDocument .setFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
} catch (PDFException | PDFSecurityException | IOException ex) {
    logger.debug("Trying to load file: " + ex);
}

...

private void drawPage(int pageNo) {
    float scale = 1.0f;
    float rotation = 0f;

    // Paint each pages content to an image
    BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) currentDocument.get().getPageImage(pageNo,
            GraphicsRenderingHints.SCREEN, Page.BOUNDARY_CROPBOX, rotation, scale);

    WritableImage fxImage = javafx.​embed.​swing.SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null);

    if (currentImage.get() != null) {
        currentImage.get().setImage(fxImage);
    } else {
        currentImage.set(new ImageView(fxImage));
    }

    //Clean up
    image.flush();
}

...

drawPage(0);
```